# I have .dll file in Visual studio 2019 C# project. How can I run this dll file directly using command line?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019, mstest

I have .dll file in Visual studio 2019 C# project using Mstest framework. How can I run this dll file directly using command line?

Comment: Presumably you want to run all of the tests contained in the DLL, rather than "run this dll"?

Comment: Using the [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) command?

Comment: no "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" test.dll   @Fildor